# LOG.error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'products'

Tags: php, laravel

I have this error LOG.error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'products'. There is sql:

```
select distinct `seller_products`.* from `seller_products` inner join `products` on `products`.`id` = `seller_products`.`product_id` and `products`.`status` = 1 inner join `products` on `seller_products`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` inner join (`category_product` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `category_product`.`category_id` and categories.id in ('4868')) on `category_product`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` where ((`seller_products`.`user_id` = 1 and exists (select * from `products` where `seller_products`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and `products`.`status` = 1) and `seller_products`.`status` = 1 or exists (select * from `users` where `seller_products`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and (exists (select * from `seller_accounts` where `users`.`id` = `seller_accounts`.`user_id` and (`holiday_mode` = 0 or `holiday_date` != 2022-11-10 or (`holiday_date_start` > 2022-11-10 and `holiday_date_end` < 2022-11-10 or `holiday_date_start` > 2022-11-10 or `holiday_date_end` < 2022-11-10))) and exists (select * from `seller_subcriptions` where `users`.`id` = `seller_subcriptions`.`seller_id` and `expiry_date` > 2022-11-10 and exists (select * from `users` where `seller_subcriptions`.`seller_id` = `users`.`id` and exists (select * from `seller_accounts` where `users`.`id` = `seller_accounts`.`user_id` and `seller_commission_id` = 3))) and `is_active` = 1 or exists (select * from `seller_accounts` where `users`.`id` = `seller_accounts`.`user_id` and (`seller_commission_id` != 3 and `holiday_mode` = 0 or `holiday_date` != 2022-11-10 or (`holiday_date_start` > 2022-11-10 and `holiday_date_end` < 2022-11-10 or `holiday_date_start` > 2022-11-10 or `holiday_date_end` < 2022-11-10))) and `is_active` = 1)) and `seller_products`.`status` = 1) and exists (select * from `products` where `seller_products`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and (`products`.`id` in (6147) or `products`.`product_name` LIKE %walizka-american-tourister-linex-66-cm-deep-navy% or `products`.`description` LIKE %walizka-american-tourister-linex-66-cm-deep-navy% or `products`.`specification` LIKE %walizka-american-tourister-linex-66-cm-deep-navy%)) or `seller_products`.`product_name` LIKE %walizka-american-tourister-linex-66-cm-deep-navy%) and (`seller_products`.`user_id` = 1 and exists (select * from `products` where `seller_products`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and `products`.`status` = 1) and `seller_products`.`status` = 1 or exists (select * from `users` where `seller_products`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and (exists (select * from `seller_accounts` where `users`.`id` = `seller_accounts`.`user_id` and (`holiday_mode` = 0 or `holiday_date` != 2022-11-10 or (`holiday_date_start` > 2022-11-10 and `holiday_date_end` < 2022-11-10 or `holiday_date_start` > 2022-11-10 or `holiday_date_end` < 2022-11-10))) and exists (select * from `seller_subcriptions` where `users`.`id` = `seller_subcriptions`.`seller_id` and `expiry_date` > 2022-11-10 and exists (select * from `users` where `seller_subcriptions`.`seller_id` = `users`.`id` and exists (select * from `seller_accounts` where `users`.`id` = `seller_accounts`.`user_id` and `seller_commission_id` = 3))) and `is_active` = 1 or exists (select * from `seller_accounts` where `users`.`id` = `seller_accounts`.`user_id` and (`seller_commission_id` != 3 and `holiday_mode` = 0 or `holiday_date` != 2022-11-10 or (`holiday_date_start` > 2022-11-10 and `holiday_date_end` < 2022-11-10 or `holiday_date_start` > 2022-11-10 or `holiday_date_end` < 2022-11-10))) and `is_active` = 1)) and `seller_products`.`status` = 1)
```

Can somebody help me?

This is an error from amazCart cms

Comment: The `products` table gets JOINed _multiple_ times here, so each occurrence needs its own alias.

Answer (score 0):

Every table specified in an SQL statement needs to have a unique alias.  You're fine to join the same table more than once, but if you do then you have to give each instance of the table a different alias.

You appear to be joining the 'products' table more than once.
You'll need to use something like `JOIN products AS products2` and use this `products2` reference in the SQL join criteria.